# Can't target ul items in DIV with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a theme which can be seen at http://flexibletheme.tumblr.com/ for the code (not much there right now) and I can't  target the list items with any CSS code.

It only works if I use:

---

ul {list-style: none;
}

This targets all unorded lists, but I just want to target the #followed DIV. Below is an image of the effected area and is titled "People I follow".

Edit: It appears I also can't target the DIV.

---

[image: image of list problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS is fine, and `div#followed ul li { list-style-type: none; }` should do the trick. However, you have a mismatched closing tag. You open your `div`, open your `ul`, then close the `div` before closing the `ul`. This is invalid markup, and is likely the reason the browser isn't matching the proper element. Also, you're missing an opening quotation mark in the `div` with the id "followed". Try this code instead, it worked for me:

```
<div id="followed">
<ul>

        <li>
            <img src="http://30.media.tumblr.com/avatar_eaa1e0c62645_48.png"/>
            <a href="http://firstbook.tumblr.com/">firstbook</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="http://29.media.tumblr.com/avatar_a8edff4a4450_48.png"/>
            <a href="http://doctorswithoutborders.tumblr.com/">doctorswithoutborders</a>
        </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

In the future, you can fix these problems by being more careful. Also, the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is a useful tool for pinpointing invalid markup.

Comment: Doesn't work. I even tried the full CSS path (via Firebug) which was html body div#wrap div#main aside div.block div#followed" ul

Comment: Are you just trying to hide the bullet? In that case, try `list-style-type: none;`

Comment: That also doesn't work, just noticed I can't target anything in the DIV. Must be a different problem, unrelated to the list-style. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you post your CSS, I can take a look.

Comment: It's live at http://flexibletheme.tumblr.com/ and the CSS is inline currently.

Edit: Unless you want me to post it somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks Zach, danontheline found it was a syntax error that was mucking up everything. Thanks for the targeting CSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When I add Zach's CSS rule to the bottom of your inline CSS, it seems to work (removes the bullets). I would comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet...

Comment: I added it to the source code which is live, it's still not working in Firefox/Chrome/Opera.

Answer (score 0):

You can't target the div, because there's a syntax error! You got double quotes "" at the end of `<div id="followed"">`
Zach Rattner is actually right, just use

```
#followed ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Got it to work, it was just that quote at the end that was causing the trouble. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: A little hint as I saw you had the same problem not too long ago: Use a proper html editor of your choice that will highlight and color code for you. That way you will always see if there's a quote missing or too much!